# Cordova include GoogleMaps in <a href="">

Tags: html, cordova, maps

i'm new to Stackoverflow but i've read a lot!

I'm from Germany, so sorry if sth is unclear.

Im new to Cordova. I'm programming an App for tourists. I have a Button inside my App called "Card". I would like to show my position inside the app when someone clicks on the Button but that doesn't work :-/

What i tried was:

```
<script>
function success(position) {
var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
mapcanvas.style.width = '600px';

document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

var options = {
zoom: 15,
center: coords,
mapTypeControl: false,
navigationControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
},
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: coords,
  map: map,
  title:"You are here!"
});
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
error('Geo Location is not supported');
}

</script>
```

and then in HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="success()"></a>
```

without the first space, but stack doesn't display the code without it.

I hope, that someone can help me. A tutorial how to change my code for making it work would be great!

Greeting!

**EDIT: How to solve this problem:** 
Guys...it was MUCH easier!!

I just added `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.maps.google.de/', '_blank', 'location=yes', 'presentationstyle=fullscreen')"></a>`

to my button... now it opens it like i want to open it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these html. its working one.

```
 <DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('maps', '3', {
                        other_params: 'sensor=false'
                        });

       google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    function initialize() {
                                  initializeMap();
       }

    function initializeMap()
    {
        $("#map").html("");
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                  zoom: 12,
                                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.083300, 34.800000),
                                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                  mapTypeControl:false,
                                  streetViewControl:false,

                                  });
                                  alert("Map Started--------------------");
    }



function getlocation()
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
var lnglat;
   var mylocationpng = 'mylocation.png';
   var mymarker=null;
function onSuccess(position)
{
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;

     lnglat = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
     var currentlocationpng = new google.maps.MarkerImage(mylocationpng,new google.maps.Size(42, 42));
     map.panTo(lnglat);

            if(mymarker==null)
            {
                mymarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                  position: lnglat,
                                                  draggable: false,
                                                  icon: currentlocationpng,
                                                  map: map
                                                  });

            }
            else
            {
                //alert('again');
                mymarker.setPosition(lnglat);

            }
        //alert('done');
}

function onError()
{
    alert("Can't show current location");
}


    </script>
</head>
    <body>

    <div id="temp">
    <img src="mylocation.png" width="30" height="30" id="mylocation" onclick="getlocation()"/>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your

> `function success(position)`

, require "position" but when you call function you don't send it everything??

```
<a href="#" onclick="success()"></a>
```

you can create function ex:

```
> function get_location(){ 
>     if (navigator.geolocation) 
>     { 
>           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success); 
>     } else 
>     {
>         error('Geo Location is not supported'); 
>     }  }
```

and call it went user click

```
<a href="#" onclick="get_location()"></a>
```

Comment: i just changed it to "onclick="success(position)">" but doesn't work :-/

Sorry, i'm not so good at html

Comment: "position" are you sure position is not NULL ??

Comment: is it the wrong function i use for gettin the position from the user?

Comment: you can create function ex:
function get_location(){
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
   } else {
      error('Geo Location is not supported');
   }
}


and call it went user click <a></a>

<a href="#" onclick="get_location()"></a>

Comment: thank you very much! And how do i send this position to googlemaps by clicking the button? 

i think, cordova says "target" must be "_blank" for open it inside the app.

Comment: Click button not different with <a></a>

<input type="button" id="btnGen" value="Click" onclick="get_location()" />

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 geolocation the following way:

```
function getPosition() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (data) {
            var position = data.coords;
            //call your success function
            success(position);
        }, function (error) {
            //whatever
        });
    } else {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

In your link set onclick on this function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getPosition()"></a>
```

Use the received coordinates like this in your success() function:

```
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you, i think, thats better. Getting the position now works i think. But i don't know, how to implement it, that googlemaps open up when someone clicks the button :-(

Comment: Do you want to open google maps website or do you want to show the map element inside your app? I don't understand what you want. In the code you provided it looks like you want to display the map on a canvas element on your website. Can you explain what is your plan?

Comment: Okay i will try to explain it:

My App is for tourists. There are 4 Buttons in the Footer of the app. News/Weather/Map/Home
News and Weather are realised over the inappbrowser. And now, if you click on "Map" it should bring you to googlemaps and show your position. Is that clear enough or is it still not clear? :-/

/Edit: I dont want the app to open the "Maps" App on the iphone directly. It should bring you to googlemaps via the inappbrowser with a function to get back to the app. :-/ I hope, you now know what i mean?!